# Group in a loop in the tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Can I group in a loop in the tidyverse?

The bigger task is to replace a grouping variable with `NA` if there are few observations in the group. I want to consolidate small groups into an `NA` group.

However, the code below won't let me `group_by(x)` where `x` is the looping variable.

```
library(tidyverse)

for (x in c("cyl", "gear")) {
    mtcars %>%
        add_count(x) %>% 
        mutate(x = ifelse(n() < 10, NA, x))
}
```

I receive the following error.

```
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `x` is unknown
```

Comment: Sorry, made a mistake. Your `x` is a character string, not a variable. It should be `group_by(get(x))` if you want to group. I don't understand why `add_count`, also with `get(x)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
for (x in c("cyl", "gear")) {
  col <- sym(x)
  mtcars <- mtcars %>%
    add_count(!!col) %>% 
    mutate(!!col := ifelse(n < 10, NA, !!col)) %>% 
    select(-n)
}
mtcars
#> # A tibble: 32 x 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  21      NA  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4
#>  2  21      NA  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4
#>  3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1
#>  4  21.4    NA  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1
#>  5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2
#>  6  18.1    NA  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1
#>  7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4
#>  8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> 10  19.2    NA  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

(Not the easiest syntax, I know....)

Comment: Amended previous answer. You need that "select(-n)", otherwis add_count in the cycle will create an additional new count column each time, and the mutate will use the wrong column.

Comment: It's enough to do: `mtcars <- mtcars %>%
    add_count(!! col) %>% 
    mutate(!! col := ifelse(n < 10, NA, !! col)) %>%
    select(-n)`

Comment: @arg0naut You're right. Did not know that add_count was able to do the grouping under the hood!  Will amend again.

Comment: Indeed it does grouping and aggregating at the same time, you got my upvote!

Comment: What is the `!!` operator? How do I learn more about it? At least the solution wasn't something obvious! :)

Comment: @RichardHerron  `!!` is the so-called "bang-bang" operator. "Welcome" to tidyeval! You're in for a ride... ;-) Jokes aside:  dplyr functions are generally "made" as to use bare column names. If you want to pass them anything else (e.g., a variable corresponding to a string containing the column name as in this case), you have to use some "tricks". See here for a gentle intro: https://timmastny.rbind.io/blog/nse-tidy-eval-dplyr-leadr/

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `mutate_at` with `table`

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear), ~ {
            t <- table(.)
            ifelse(. %in% names(t[t < 10]), NA, .)})
```

The function can be simplified to one line with `purrr::keep`

```
mtcars %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear),
            ~ ifelse(. %in% names(keep(table(.), `<`, 10)), NA, .))
```

Or if you happen to be working with a data.table, you can use an "update join" to subset to groups with low counts, then assign `NA` to that subset

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(mtcars)

for(x in c('cyl', 'gear'))
  dt[dt[, .N, x][N < 10], on = x, (x) := NA]
```

This will achieve the same result

```
all.equal(
  dt, 
  mtcars %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(cyl, gear),
    ~ ifelse(. %in% names(keep(table(.), `<`, 10)), NA, .)) %>% 
    setDT
)
# [1] TRUE
```